# Как называется таблица для связи "многие ко многим"?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Таблицы для связи "многие ко многим" часто называют так: "Таблица1_Таблица2".
Нас в универе учили, что такие таблицы называются фондом. [Один работник может работать над несколькими проектами, и на один проект может быть назначено несколько людей, тогда соединительную таблицу можно назвать "Фонд сотрудников" или "Фонд проектов". И т. п.]

В прошлом году слышал ещё одно название для таких таблиц, оно вроде звучало лучше, чем "Фонд".
Так вот, какие ещё есть варианты названия таких таблиц, подскажите пожалуйста?

Спасибо всем, все помогли :)

Comment: Связующая? Гуглится в конектсе СУБД.

Comment: «У одного человека может быть несколько телефонов» — это уже связь «один ко многим».

Comment: @andreymal одним телефоном могут пользоваться несколько человек

Comment: Из формулировки, указанной вопросе, в первую очередь получается «один ко многим». Да и не видел я ни разу баз, где можно было бы привязать несколько человек к одному телефону

Comment: Да, это я жёстко тупанул, с телефонами действительно один ко многим) Исправил.

Comment: Развязочная таблица.

Comment: > Да и не видел я ни разу баз, где можно было бы привязать несколько человек к одному телефону

называется "кабинет".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называть по сути можно как удобно "фонд", "словарь" и т.п. Но на практике обычно отталкиваются от семантики предметной области, в которой реализуется задача. В данном случае вашу таблицу можно назвать "Абоненты".

Answer (score 5):

Да как угодно. Таблица-связка, соединительная таблица. Разве это имеет какое-то существенно значение? Впрочем "фонд" - это что-то бессмысленное, ни разу не слышал подобных наименований

Comment: Может и нет, просто вопрос засел в голове, не даёт покоя)

Answer (score 1):

Такие таблицы называются "сводные". Кстати, почему именно фонд телефонов? Может, фонд людей. Они ведь многие ко многим=). Ну это так, к размышлению.

Comment: Можно в принципе, но ведь имеется в виду, что у человека может быть несколько телефонов, а не у телефона может быть несколько людей :)

Comment: В данном конкретном случае имеется ввиду, что связь "многие ко многим". Так что да, у телефона может быть много людей=). А если у человека много телефонов - это связь "один ко многим", и никаких промежуточных таблиц не нужно.

Comment: Угу, я тупанул) Исправил формулировку вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Внесу и я свои 5 копеек (просто для разнообразия вариантов) - промежуточная таблица.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве еще одного варианта могу предложить использовать префикс LNK_ (сращение от link), например LNK_PEOPEL_PHONE. Иногда бывает удобно, когда в дереве структуры БД эти таблицы расположены рядом.